# How can I remove a user order item using django view and model

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am following an ecommerce tutorial in Django which uses allauth and allauth.account in the installed app. I have the following models: Item, OrderItem, and Order. The item model code is below:

```
class Item(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
price = models.FloatField()
discount_price = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
category = models.CharField(
    choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, max_length=2, default="S")
label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1, default="P")
slug = models.SlugField()
description = models.TextField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

## Remove Particular Product from cart by id using url

```
def get_remove_from_cart_url(self):
    return reverse("core:remove-from-cart", kwargs={
        'slug': self.slug
    })
```

Model for OrderItem:

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)

ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
item = models.ForeignKey(Item, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.user.username} has {self.quantity} of {self.item.title}"
```

Model for Order

```
class Order(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                         on_delete=models.CASCADE)
items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()
ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

In my views.py, here is my method for removing item from cart:

```
def remove_from_cart(request, slug):
# Getting the Item
item = get_object_or_404(Item, slug=slug)
# Check if the user has an order
order_qs = Order.objects.filter(
    user=request.user,
    ordered=False)
# if the user have an order
if order_qs.exists():
    # Then grap it (the order)
    order = order_qs[0]
    # check if the ordered item is in the order by filtering
    if order.items.filter(item__slug=item.slug).exists():
        order_item = OrderItem.objects.filter(
            item=item,
            user=request.user,
            ordered=False
        )[0]
        # Then Remove it

        order.items.remove(order_item)
        messages.info(request, 'This Item was Removed your Cart.')
    else:
        messages.info(request, 'This Item was NOT in your Cart.')
        # Add a message saying the order does not contain the item
        return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)
else:
    messages.info(request, 'The User Does No have an Order.')
    # Add a message saying the user does not exist
    return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)
return redirect("core:product", slug=slug)
```

The issue here is that whenever remove item from cart, I will also get a message which says This Item was Removed your Cart but it is not reflected in database. Thanks for your kind assistance

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that I did not know how django admin removes items from my Order table. While following the tutorial I  understand that when the item is highlighted that is when it is still in the Order table but whenever it is not highlighted that is when the item is removed, though you might be physically seeing it there.
Here is a screen shot when Item is in the cart (Order Model):
[Item is added to cart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIOCn.png)

Here is when I click on Remove Item from cart url then database shows this:
[Item is removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0prGC.png)

Someone should correct me if my answer was not true